# Preferred method for REST-style URL's?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I am creating a web application that incorporates REST-style services and I wanted some clarification as to the preferred (standard) method of how the POST requests should be accepted by my Java server side:

Method 1:
http://localhost:8080/services/processser/uid/{uidvalue}/eid/{eidvalue}

Method 2:
http://localhost:8080/services/processuser
{uid:"",eid:""} - this would be sent as JSON in the post body

Both methods would use the "application/json" content-type, but are there advantages, disadvantages to each method. One disadvantage to method 2, I can immediately think of is that the JSON data, would need to be mapped to a Java Object, thus creating a Java object any time any user access the "processuser" servlet api. Your input is much appreciated.

In this particular instance, the data would be used to query the database, to return a json response back to the client.

Comment: The first thing you should make clear is what "processuser" is. Namely, does the post data change the state of the resource?

Comment: What Artefacto said, plus: Don't worry about creating an object to parse your JSON unless you've proven it to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think we need to go back a little from your question. Your path segment starts with:

```
/services/processuser
```

This is a mistake. The URI should identify a resource, not an operation. This may not be always possible, but it's something you should strive for.

In this case, you seem to identify your user with a `uid` and an `eid` (whatever those are). You could build paths such as a user is referred to by `/user/<uid>/<eid>`,  `/user/<uid>-<eid>` (if you must `/user/uid/<uid>/eid/<eid>`); if `eid` is a specialization, and not on equal footing with `uid`, then `/user/<uid>;eid=<eid>` would be more appropriate.

You would create new users by posting to `/user/` or `/user/<uid>/<eid>` if you knew the identifiers in advance, deleting users by using DELETE on `/user/<uid>/<eid>` and **change state** by using PUT on `/user/<uid>/<eid>`.

So to answer your question, you should use PUT on `/user/<uid>/<eid>` if "processuser" aims to change the state of the user with data you provide. Otherwise, the mapping to the REST model is not so clean, possibly the best option would be to define a resource `/user/process/<uid>/<eid>` and POST there with all the data, but a POST to `/user/process` with all the data would be more or less the same, since we're already in RPC-like camp.

Comment: I assumed processuser was some sort of object, good call on the RPC point.

Answer (score 0):

For POST requests, Method 2 is usually preferred, although often the resource name will be pluralized, so that you actually post to:

```
http://localhost:8080/services/processusers
```

This is for creating new records, however.

It looks like you're really using what most RESTful services would use a GET request for (retrieving a record), in which case, Method 1 is preferred.

Edit:
I realize I didn't source my answer, so consider the standards set by [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). You may or may not agree that it is a valid standard.